# gaps in background color of parent in childs element

Tags: html, css, overflow, hidden

I try to make parent div - background color, rounded corners and overflow hidden,
put inside child div with background color, but I see small gap of parent color.
How can it be and how to fix this?
the main task is not to change the HTML

[image]

here code
https://codepen.io/batareika007/pen/ZERWmBM

```css
.container {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  /*  if you make background white, you see the gap more clearly  */
  /*   background: white; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">some content here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

tried position, z-index, play with the borders...

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the child's bottom padding with the parent's bottom border.

Now you can change the height of the child, but you'd also need to adapt the height of the parent.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100px - 1rem);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1rem solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
  background: red;
}

.child {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 0 1rem;
  background: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  /*  if you make background white, you see the gap more clearly  */
  /*   background: white; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">some content here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I think in that case we just can remove the child element and flex, so the style will the same =)  The main purpose is that we can change the child's height, content, even move it via position relative, but it must stay inside the parent.

Comment: Here's another solution that works with a dynamic height, but only as long as you change the paren't height as well. You have to be more specific about how you want it to change based on content or multiple children.

Answer (score 0):

Adding height or padding to the parent element causes this issue to happen.
I'm not sure if this is problem with chrome's engine or just a bug.
Here's a hacky solution.

Remove `overflow: hidden` from the `parent`.

Add a `box-shadow` with the same `background-color` as the `child` to the `child`.

Offset the `box-shadow` down a bit.

And finaly add `border-radius` to the `child`.

```css
.container{
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.parent{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;  
}
.child{
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    border-radius: 0 0 1rem 1rem;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgb(230 230 230);
/*  if you make background white, you see the gap more clearly  */
/*   background: white; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">some content here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment, unfortunate I must the parent to be 'overflow:hidden', but in static way if the content never changes, it can be useful thanks !